using a external hard drive for back ups
this is a very newbie question, im using ubuntu 20.04 but want to upgrade, first I want to back up my home folder to a seagate portable hard drive.
It seems to mount ok and once open,  there are files pre-loaded there: for using windows, registration autorun.info etc.
I have never used one before, is it fine just to drag and drop the files I want to save as it is, straight out of the box? or is formatting essential?
When i searched for using an external hard drive with linux, I just found lots of info about formatting and wondered if this is something absolutely necessary before I can use it as I would rather not as not sure what I am doing and dont want to mess it up.
If formatting is essential would lots of USBs be a better option to save files or is there a very simple way of formatting using GUI if I stick with the hard drive?

Instead of copying files to the external disk I suggest creating an archive using tar, this way permissions will be kept without requiring a specific format of the external disk.
tar cvf /external-mountpoint/backup$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).tar $HOME


You should be fine with that external hard drive.  There should be no issue deleting material already on that external drive.  Some of the external hard drives I've purchased were ready to use out of the box.  In every case, I have renamed the drive to something meaningful (to me).  In some cases, it might be best to reformat the drive.  If it is formatted NTFS, it will work with Windows or Linux as would one formatted one of the FAT flavors.  If it comes formatted some sort of FAT, I would definitely reformat the drive.
Files can be simply dragged and dropped onto the drive.
To see what the file format is, and as required, to change it, I use the disks application, which is actually the gnome-disks application.  It probably comes with the Ubuntu system but if not, it can be apt installed.  Using that application you will be shown the partition format.  You can delete the existing partition using the red minus application at the right and, using the gears icon near the left to make and format a new application.

how do i find out what it is formatted to? I would prefer not to attempt formatting as I am very useless as anything technical and do not understand what id be doing enough

so would it be ok just deleting what is on there and then dragging/ dropping the files i want to save. Like when I use a USB?

@papercup - I've added your further questions to the answer

You can backup using filevault right?

filevault? A Search with Google implies filevault is an Apple thing.
